# Install/Use same bundle multiple times

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, composer-php

Does anyone knows if you can install/use the same bundle multiple times in Symfony2?

For example I would need to have 3 different registration forms based on FOSUserBundle, and so far I have achieved this by creating my own services (forms, form handlers, form factory ...) and my own controllers for 2 out of 3 types of users.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to achieve? You want implement 3 various versions of your own user-bundle implementation?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: But for what? You can just create as many forms as you need and all of them will use FOSUserBundle.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to inherit FOSUserBundle several time.

You can create 3 différents form type in order to achieve this.

See the documentation : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Hope it's helpful.
Best regard

Comment: I can override the forms only once, as I have to specify in the config.yml which form to be used by FOS. If I have 3 registration forms how can I tell FOS bundle to use my form?

I tried overriding the config from a controller and it says  I cannot override a frozen parameter bag.

Comment: But you can use form event in order to dynamically change the form. see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10462867/1335198